# vuejs component that inherits parent's context

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Let's start from this

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error':determineError('content')}">
  <label>Content Label</label>
  <div class="mandat">*</div>
  <input v-model="form.content" name="content" v-validate="'required|min:5|max:100'" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The first thing I would like to obtain is to put this piece of code somehow inside a component, something like this:

```
Vue.component('form-group', {
    ...
    template: `<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error':determineError('content')}">
      <label>Content Label</label>
      <div class="mandat">*</div>
      <input v-model="form.content" name="content" v-validate="'required|min:5|max:100'" class="form-control">
    </div>`
});
```

As you can see I still have the input field right there. What I would like to do is pass any piece of code instead and the current component must inherit parent's context.

Something like

```
<form-group>
  <template>
    <input v-model="form.content" name="content" v-validate="'required|min:5|max:100'" class="form-control">
  </template>
</form-group>
```

How can this be achieved? Notice that I still use parent's context. If using parent's context is not possible, then how can I achieve this in the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html), which are expanded in the component template with the contents passed by the parent.

In the `form-group` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error':determineError('content')}">
    <label>Content Label</label>
    <div class="mandat">*</div>
    <slot v-bind:form="form"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also add a fallback content inside the `<slot>` (a default input maybe). Note we are passing the context for the slot contents (see [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)).